# Is an ArcMap 10.0 Add-In compatible with ArcMap 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-9.3, add-in

I'm working on an Add-In for ArcMap 10.0 in .NET version 3.5. This add-in works fine with ArcMap 10.0. Now I want to use this add-in in ArcMap 9.3. But I couldn't add Add-In .dll file in ArcMap 9.3.

**QUESTION:**

Is there any process to use ArcMap 10.0 Add-In in ArcMap 9.3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The add-in model is a new feature in version 10.0. This means you will not be able to use an add-in at lower versions, which require you to implement your commands, extensions, toolbars etc. in the older COM-only model.

Comment: Is there any different implement issue in older COM-only model? or I have to just recompile my toolbar in older sdk?

Comment: It's just a different way of extending ArcObjects, which was the only way at 9.3 and can of course still be used at 10. See the documentation for 9.3: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/dotnet/c65c39e2-a141-4975-9096-d347454478b1.htm